# I want to change mui MobileDatePicker calendar to DatePickerCalendar

Tags: datepicker, material-ui, calendar

When Mui MobileDatePicker was clicked, calendar likes picture 1.(left)

but I want to show calendar like picture 2(right) to the user.

how can i change the calendar?

The reason I want to use MobileDatePicker is to remove the calendar icon next to textfield in DatePicker.
If there is a way to get rid of the icon and make the calendar appear when the text is clicked, DatePicker would be great.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `showToolbar` props to show/hide toolbar in MobileDatePicker. for more customization check https://mui.com/api/mobile-date-picker/

```
'''
  <MobileDatePicker
    ...
    showToolbar={false}
/>
...
```

Comment: thank you :)
It was a big help!!
Is there any way to display a calendar without an icon using Datepicker?